# How do I setup Rails Associations with Devise and scaffold generated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I'm using rails 3.1 with Devise for user authentication...

I'm having trouble either getting the associations between two scaffold generated models working or I'm not accessing it correctly.

I have two models: User (Devise), and Post

I've added the `belongs_to :user` tag in the Post model and `has_many :posts` in the User model.

When I open a rails console, `rails c` from terminal in the app directory, I thought I should be able to reference the Post model through the user model. Such as `User.post.count` but I keep getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method "post"` error.

I've been through all the guide.rails.org and back through the railstutorial.org book and I'm definitely missing something somewhere.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are two potential problems here.  Posts are associated with a particular user, so User.post.count doesn't really make any sense.  If you have a user object (user = User.first), then you could reasonably ask for how many posts they have with user.posts.count, but it should be plural...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added your migrations that adds  `user_id` to the posts table?  Without that foreign key, Rails can't figure out which users are associated with which posts.